# Oxite: What are you going to do with it?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, oxite

Microsoft released the source for [Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=20210), their blogging engine that's intended to help .NET developers learn ASP.NET MVC. They also released the source for the [Mix](http://visitmix.com/) site, which was built with Oxite.

Microsoft says that developers can build applications with Oxite, since it has a lot of built-in features like trackbacks, pingbacks, and RSS support.

Are you going to use Oxite to learn ASP.NET MVC? Do you think you could do anything useful with it?

Comment: Why isn't this a community wiki?

Comment: @diego, because it's a programming-related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would stay away from it. It's a very bad example. I don't understand why microsoft put it on internet. First of all the security reasons, but the code is very hard to read for new developers. I use asp.net mvc since preview 2, but it's still very difficult to read that code because it's bad. Many better examples are found or used here on stack overflow.
Personally I suggest watching the screencasts on Rob Connery's website or on [Autumnofagile](http://www.autumnofagile.net)

[Karl Seguin took the time to sum it all up](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/12/15/oxite-oh-dear-lord-why.aspx)

[Rob Connery works for Microsoft and doesn't like it either](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/some-thoughts-on-oxite/)

[A new word is named after it: Oxitis](http://frickinsweet.com/ryanlanciaux.com/post/Do-you-have-this-condition.aspx)

Comment: Correction to autumnofagile link:
http://www.autumnofagile.net/

Comment: I wish I would have read it before hand only.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend staying clear of Oxite as an example of how to write an ASP.NET MVC application.  In it's current form, it's fundamentally flawed and will do more damage than good.

Comment: what are the fundamental flaws?

Answer (score 2):

First off, Oxite in it's current form is a Blog Engine, not a CMS.  You can add pages, but that is hardly a CMS.  Secondly, I'm going to wait and see what happens this week now that Rob Conery is doing some severe refactoring on it.  Refactoring that was sorely needed.  I think with his input and the continued effort of the team, it will get over the initial problems that many have had with it.  So I think I will probably adopt it as my blogging platform and hopefully integrate it with my CMS.

Comment: I saw that on his blog today. He posted screencaps of the new project structure. Obviously I respect and admire the guy; thus, my question about Oxite and his concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't seen this before. Looks interesting.

> What are you going to do with it?

If someone wants me to write a CMS and specifies that I must use .NET, then I'll look at oxite as a possible alternative to things like DotNetNuke. I don't know anything about either of them though :-)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the source, but I don't think I can do anything with it until Rob refactors it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious if there's been any movement in the opinion on this app? I might like to give it a whirl, although I'd also want to look at it as a model (so to speak) for doing MVC development with ASP.Net MVC. If this is not a good example of code to follow, does anyone have suggestions for alternative applications that are relatively feature-ful and employ good coding practice, using the ASP.Net MVC stack? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I read at the Mix website that the Oxite source code is "componentized" enough such that WebForms developers can take advantage of it too. Since I'm not ready to go with ASP.NET MVC for my projects yet, Oxite might be a good way for me to figure out how to transition from a WebForms app to an ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: There's not need to transition to MVC. MVC is a choice alongside web forms. MBC is not the "new" webforms, nor is it a replacement for it, it's just a different way of doing things.

Comment: While there is not a transition need in terms of the technology and its lifespan, there is a need for me to learn MVC. Thus, the transition teaches me MVC while using what I already know.